# Filter multiple columns in Pandas data frame for same string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am looking for an easy and efficient way to filter multiple columns in pandas data frame with same string (`'Normal'`). These columns have specific suffix `(_out)` and can be filtered using `regex` like

```
df_out.filter(regex='_out')
```

Currently I am using individual filters like

`Filter_1 = df_out[‘column1_out’].isin([‘Normal])` and then `df_out[Filter_1]`

But having more than **`30 of these columns`**, I feel there has to be a lean way of getting this done.

Comment: Can you show the sample dataframe

Comment: I am not the one who downvote you

Comment: No worry buddy, I gave up looking into stack upvote/downvote  almost 8 years back! Showing my data structure is quite difficult as most of my `_out cols` are getting created on the fly. But I got a good hint in the answer below by @Ynjxsjmh, I can take it forward from there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df_out.columns.str.contains('_out')` to extract all the columns that contains `_out`.

```py
mask = np.logical_and.reduce([df_out[col].isin(['Normal']) for col in df_out.columns[df_out.columns.str.contains('_out')]])
df_out[mask]
```

Or

```py
mask = np.logical_and.reduce([df_out[col].isin(['Normal']) for col in df_out.filter(regex='_out').columns])
df_out[mask]
```